# How to implement ShowDialog mock method for unit test for vsPackage(VS 2013)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, vsix, vspackage

I am writing a vsPackage for VS 2013 and need to show a modal dialog window. I need to write a unit test, but ShowDialog method is not defined in any of IVsUIShell interfaces. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap `ShowDialog` up behind your own class that implements an interface. When testing code that normally would call `ShowDialog`, inject a mock object.